# Python click module. Show color in windows and mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-click

I need to show messages with color in MacOS and in Windows terminal. I used `click`, and tried that code:

```
def print_error(
        message,  # type: str
):  # type: (...) -> None
    error_word = click.style('ERROR: ', fg='red')
    click.echo(error_word + click.style(message, bg=bg, bold=bold, underline=underline, blink=blink), err=True)
```

But I got white text on MacOS, not red. If I change `click.echo` to `print`, everything will be great. But I don't think that it is a good idea.

[image: First one is a click.echo, second one - print]

Why doesn't `click.echo` function show me selected color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the main problem. I ran python script, using cmake. When I ran it through cmake, python don't have any tty now, and function `isatty()` will return False. In that library, it means that it is a file, and `click` delete ANSI codes.